# Browser strips encoded dot character from url

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I have a web app, which allows searching. So when I go to `somedomain.com/search/<QUERY>` it searches for entities according to `<QUERY>`. The problem is, when I try to search for `.` or `..` it doesn't work as expected (which is pretty obvious). What surprised me though, is that if I manually enter the url of `somedomain.com/search/%2E`, the browser (tested Chrome and IE11) converts it `somedomain.com/search/` and issues a request without necessary payload.

So far I haven't found anything that would say it's not possible to make this work, so I came here. Right now I have only one option: replacing `.` and `..` to something like `__dotPlaceholder__`, but this feels like a dirty hack to me.

Any solution (js or non-js) will be welcomed. Any information on why do browsers strip url-encoded dots is also a nice-to-have.

Comment: could this possibly be a server redirect problem?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I think not. If I open Chrome dev console, it shows me that the only request being made is the one with `%2E` already stripped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately part of RFC3986 defines the URI dot segments to be normalised and stripped out in that case, ie `http://example.com/a/./` to become `http://example.com/a`

see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-33 for more information